# how mongo db does locking for updates/inserts?

Tags: mongodb, update, locking, insert

I have many data for each user that with write heavy and many for each separate users that there is not any relation between user's data; so there is two options for me to store them:
1. keep all user's data in one collection that is much easier, and
2. keep every user's data in a separate collection;
Now i need to know is a locking battle-neck for parallel writes in first option or not, while my updates/inserts are many but on one by one (there is no need to update/insert many (multi: true).
does mongo lock the whole collection for an updateOne/insertOne (multe: false) or only does it for updateMany/insertMany (multi: true) cases?

Answer (score 0):

According the documentation MongoDB locks the database only when create an index in the foreground ( this option does not exists any more in MongoDB 4.2. ).

On the other hand the collection are never exclusively locks.

See more what locks are taken on MongoDB on [What locks are taken by some common client operations?](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/concurrency/)